# its possible to put a default value to a parameter of a function in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, oop

its just like that in other langauges (php in the example)

```
function myFunction($message,$sender="nodoby") {
return $message." by ".$sender;
}
```

no body told me use overload !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use

```
Public Function MyFun(Optional myParam As String = "MyDefaultValue")
```